# JBoss dev studio - Unable to import openshift project

Tags: git, jboss, openshift, jboss-tools

I have setup an openshift account and added a gear.
After downloading jboss dev studio, signing in and setting up the ssh keys, I tried to import the project into the workspace.
When jboss in launched without admin privileges it shows me an error about authentication problems, and when I run in with admin priv the loading process will run endlessly.
I can clone my project by using git bash and rhc git-clone commands that means the ssh key is configured correctly, also I added the ssh key to jboss preferences.
Can anyone help me finding why I cannot import my project.
Thanks in advance.
Regards

Answer (score 0):

Can you provide a little more information?  Here are the steps that you go through to import an openshift application:

1. Open JBoss studio
2. File>New>Openshift Application
3. Should prompt you to login.  Supply your username and password
4. Use my existing OpenShift Application.  Then choose browse.
5. That should provide you with a list of your applications. Choose one of them.
6. Click next and next unless you want to change where the files are going.

Of course these are very simple directions and don't allow any configuration, but it should get you going.  Can you explain which step you're getting stuck on?

Comment: Hello, yes I have followed all these steps but the problem is that the JBoss Studio stuck in a loop when loading the project. I kept it running for a long time but it was always like this.